# airflow не пускает в веб-интерфейс

Tags: apache, centos7

Пытаюсь запустить в докере apache airflow, дома все работает без проблем, в проде не пускает в веб интерфейс. Все контейнеры стартуют без проблем, если сделать запрос curl http://localhost:8080 получаю редирект на /admin/, как и должно быть, но по сети доступа нет. Порт открыт, приложения на Flask запускаются без каких-либо проблем через порт 8080. Airflow так же недоступен и на других открытых портах. ОСь centos7.
Уже сломал голову, прошу совета.
С airflow мало знаком, использую готовый compose-файл.

docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: '2.1'
services:
    redis:
        image: 'redis:5.0.5'
        # command: redis-server --requirepass redispass

    postgres:
        image: postgres:9.6
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_USER=airflow
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=airflow
            - POSTGRES_DB=airflow
        # Uncomment these lines to persist data on the local filesystem.
        #     - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
        # volumes:
        #     - ./pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata

    webserver:
        image: puckel/docker-airflow:1.10.4
        restart: always
        depends_on:
            - postgres
            - redis
        environment:
            - LOAD_EX=n
            - FERNET_KEY=46BKJoQYlPPOexq0OhDZnIlNepKFf87WFwLbfzqDDho=
            - EXECUTOR=Celery
            # - POSTGRES_USER=airflow
            # - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=airflow
            # - POSTGRES_DB=airflow
            # - REDIS_PASSWORD=redispass
        volumes:
            - ./container-data/airflow/dags:/usr/local/airflow/dags
            # Uncomment to include custom plugins
            # - ./plugins:/usr/local/airflow/plugins
        ports:
            - "8080:8080"
        command: webserver
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD-SHELL", "[ -f /usr/local/airflow/airflow-webserver.pid ]"]
            interval: 30s
            timeout: 30s
            retries: 3

    flower:
        image: puckel/docker-airflow:1.10.4
        restart: always
        depends_on:
            - redis
        environment:
            - EXECUTOR=Celery
            # - REDIS_PASSWORD=redispass
        ports:
            - "5555:5555"
        command: flower

    scheduler:
        image: puckel/docker-airflow:1.10.4
        restart: always
        depends_on:
            - webserver
        volumes:
            - ./container-data/airflow/dags:/usr/local/airflow/dags
            # Uncomment to include custom plugins
            # - ./plugins:/usr/local/airflow/plugins
        environment:
            - LOAD_EX=n
            - FERNET_KEY=46BKJoQYlPPOexq0OhDZnIlNepKFf87WFwLbfzqDDho=
            - EXECUTOR=Celery
            # - POSTGRES_USER=airflow
            # - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=airflow
            # - POSTGRES_DB=airflow
            # - REDIS_PASSWORD=redispass
        command: scheduler

    worker:
        image: puckel/docker-airflow:1.10.4
        restart: always
        depends_on:
            - scheduler
        volumes:
            - ./container-data/airflow/dags:/usr/local/airflow/dags
            # Uncomment to include custom plugins
            # - ./plugins:/usr/local/airflow/plugins
        environment:
            - FERNET_KEY=46BKJoQYlPPOexq0OhDZnIlNepKFf87WFwLbfzqDDho=
            - EXECUTOR=Celery
            # - POSTGRES_USER=airflow
            # - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=airflow
            # - POSTGRES_DB=airflow
            # - REDIS_PASSWORD=redispass
        command: worker
```

Answer (score 2):

Проблема решена. Требовалось указать докеру --network=host